# Excel using keyboard shortcut keys in formula bar

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm working on a worksheet using an `IF` statement. See the statement below. I want the date to be stamped into a different cell.

```
=IF(B2>0,TODAY()," ")
```

this puts the date into the cell but the date changes when I open it the next day. If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> it will paste the date into the cell and it won't change the next day. What do I need to enter in the formula bar to have the shortcut keys enter this date?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would to create a function entitled "StaticDate".
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd>, and create a new module.
Paste the code below, and use it in your workbook.

```
Function StaticDate() 
    StaticDate = Now 
End Function
```